# Magento 2.3.4 duplicate/clone media gallery images on 'save & duplicate' product, multistore

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, media-images, duplicate

In the admin panel, when a duplicates a product, the product pictures duplicates themselves several times, for each store exist in db.

Example,

- Have magento with 12 stores
- Have product A with 1 image - Image
- On 'Save & Duplicate' creates new product B, but with 12 copy images with different names (Image-1, Image-2, etc)

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because of the way the media gallery works in Magento. When a product is duplicated, it creates a new product entity with a new ID, but it does not create new image records in the database. Instead, it creates new references to the same images that were associated with the original product.

In your case, it seems that the media gallery is creating new copies of the images for each store view because it is associating each image with the store view.